# calling a member function on a React.Component subclass instance

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting a bit confused, coming from a background in Java.

I'm creating instances of my Class, but can't call the member functions.

> Error occurred assignment0.setLevel is not a function. (In
> 'assignment0.setLevel({ level_id: 0 })', 'assignment0.setLevel' is
> undefined)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ruwqcp?file=app%2Fmain.tsx

Why can't I call `setLevel` on `assignment0`?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
  Form,
  Field,
  FormElement,
  FieldRenderProps,
  FormRenderProps,
} from '@progress/kendo-react-form';
import { Error } from '@progress/kendo-react-labels';
import { Input } from '@progress/kendo-react-inputs';

class LevelAssignment extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  setLevel = (level) => {
    console.log('setLevel', level);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Field component={Input} label={this.props.label} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const handleSubmit = (dataItem: { [name: string]: any }) =>
    alert(JSON.stringify(dataItem, null, 2));
  const onGo = (e) => {

    var assignment0 = levelAssignmentList[0]
    console.log((assignment0));
    assignment0.setLevel({level_id:0})
  };

  const [levelAssignmentList, setLevelAssignmentList] = React.useState([]);
  var a = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    a.push(<LevelAssignment key={i} />);
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setLevelAssignmentList(a);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      render={(formRenderProps: FormRenderProps) => (
        <FormElement style={{ maxWidth: 650 }}>
          <fieldset>
            <div className="mb-3">
              {levelAssignmentList.map((Component, index) => Component)}
            </div>
          </fieldset>
          <div>
            <button type={'button'} onClick={onGo}>
              Go
            </button>
          </div>
        </FormElement>
      )}
    />
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('my-app'));
```

Comment: Tangential: it might be worth taking a step back to understand state-setting asynchronicity, JS closures, hoisting, and general ReactJS-ness.

Comment: @DaveNewton the fact that a person with your reputation said that, rather than posting an answer, has me very worried :)

Comment: Less of a “You should worry” and more “JS is very different from Java and you can’t approach it the same way because you’ll be sad” ;) There’s multiple things to keep in mind in this code—a quick step back will be more efficient in the long run (at least IMO, for whatever that’s worth (probably not much :))

Comment: @DaveNewton I totally get where you're coming from, and I will accept answers that involve redesign.  Basically I have to be able to change some state (not props) of LevelAssignment from code invoked in `onGo`

Comment: The canonical way to do that is to either (a) pass state change handlers to child components or (b) use a "higher" state management mechanism (e.g., React contexts, Redux, etc.)

Comment: I've found a solution, though I'm sure it's not exactly 'best practice'.  If I create a Parent class that encapsulates the LevelAssignment instances and the Button, I can use `ref`s to refer to the instances in the event handler.  Thanks for your guidance

Comment: Hm, interesting—hey, if it works :) I wouldn’t think refs would be needed here, but I rarely use them so I’m not in a great place to know if they make sense or not 